# How to format an array of selected timeslots into a formatted string

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm working with a scheduling system where users are able to choose timeslots in a day with **half an hour** intervals, where the selected timeslots array would look something like this:

```
['12:30', '13:00', '16:00', '16:30', '18:00']
```

I would like to display this to the user in a well-formatted output, ideally as the following:

```
"12:30pm - 1:30pm, 4:00pm - 5:00pm, 6:00pm - 6:30pm"
```

I can handle the 24hr to 12hr conversion but I can't wrap my head around how to format the time ranges and group them if they're consecutive half-hour slots.

I'm using moment.js, but I'm open to using other plugins if needed.

EDIT:
If a single, non-consecutive timeslot is chosen, such as 18:00, then the output based on the half-hour interval should be "6:00pm - 6:30pm".

Comment: Is your input array sorted as each consecutive tuple of hours are an interval and the array is always compose of an even number of elements?

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini no, users can also choose single timeslots, For example, 14:00 should be displayed as 2:00pm - 2:30pm.

Comment: each value is a half an hour slot, and you have to join slots that are attached, right?

Comment: yes that's correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need first [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) the date then use [.format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to transform the it into desired format.

```js
var arr = ['12:30', '13:00', '16:00', '16:30'];
var newArr = arr.map(function(dt) {
  return moment(dt, 'HH:mm').format('hh:mmA');
})

//Example, However it will not work if newArr is length of 3, 5
var nArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i += 2) {
  nArr.push(newArr[i] + ' ' + newArr[i + 1])
}

console.log(nArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. but formatting the times themselves isn't so much my issue, it's getting the consecutive timeslots to group with " - ", and having commas between the non-consecutives ones

Comment: @RezaKarami, I have updated answer, However its prone to error